# Why are WebRTC methods missing when run within a Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview?

Tags: javascript, .net, webrtc, webbrowser-control, microsoft-edge

In a .NET Framework 4.6.2 Windows App, I am attempting to run some WebRTC capabilities, in JavaScript, within the WebView control.  The control is from Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview (v6.1.1).

When I try to use `RTCPeerConnection.AddTransceiver()`, or `RTCPeerConnection.GetTransceivers()`, I receive the error:
`Object doesn't support property or method 'addTransceiver'`

When run directly within Edge, the code executes as expected.

Why the difference, and how can I see the exact API that is used within the WebView control context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Edge browser are you using? I assume you're using Edge Chromium so the APIs can run well in the browser.

From the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTransceiver#Browser_compatibility) of `RTCPeerConnection.addTransceiver()`, we can see that it only supports Edge Chromium. Webview control uses EdgeHTML as the rendering engine which is Edge Legacy engine, so you can't use the APIs in WebView. I also tried `RTCPeerConnection.GetTransceivers()` and it doesn't support Edge Legacy as well.

If you want to use the APIs in Microsoft Edge webview control, I suggest you to use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) which uses Microsoft Edge **Chromium** as the rendering engine to display the web content in native applications.

Comment: I didn't know about those **compatibility charts** in the Mozilla docs.  Very nice.